# Removing user arguments with discord.js commando

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, commando

I have been been making this Discord bot for Movie watching with our group.
I have run into a problem here, you need to enter a password to join, this all works fine however when the bot asks you for the password, i want to remove the chat in which the player says the password.

I have tried message.delete(); This only really either removes the original command or the bot reply.

```
async run(message, { password }) {
          if(await keyv.get('filmpassword') == password){

            let role = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "FilmBoi");

            message.member.addRole(role).catch(console.error);
            return message.say("You're in!");
          }
    }
```

Comment: "[`message.delete()`] only really either removes the original command or the bot reply." Make sure you're calling this function with the intended parameters. Some context around the function would help identify the issue.

Comment: I can only get it to remove the initial command i sent and the last message the bot has said. I am trying to remove the args i send in between.